# ssrs report report filter with no duplicates used in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I am having an issue and I'm not sure how to solve it.

I have an SSRS report that pulls from a table. I want a parameter filter to show de-duplicated values based on available options in one of the columns.

So my dataset with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE col1 IN (@param)
```

Then I want a parameter called `param` that gets its available and default values from `col1` in the above data set and I want them to be de-duplicated.

From reading [online](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36632.ssrs-remove-duplicate-filter-values-from-parameter-drop-down-using-vb-code.aspx) I learned I have to create a dummy param and use VBA code to de-duplicate that list.

So I have these params:

- `param_dummy` that gets its available and default values from `col1` in the above dataset
- `param` that gets a de-duplicate list from `param_dummy` using `Code.RemoveDuplicates`

But I'm having an issue with circular logic. `param` gets its value from `param_default` which gets its value from the dataset/query which uses `param`.

How can I solve this?

One thought is to remove the `WHERE col1 IN (@param)` and instead use a filter on the Tablix table in the SSRS report. This works but I am wondering how efficient it is.

And/or if anyone has any other suggestions I am all ears.

## Updated to add more details...

So let us say I have a table in my DB like so:

```
| id | col1 | col2   |
|----|------|--------|
| 1  | a    | hello  |
| 2  | b    | how    |
| 3  | a    | are    |
| 4  | c    | you    |
| 5  | d    | on     |
| 6  | a    | this   |
| 7  | b    | lovely |
| 8  | c    | day    |
```

What I want is:

- a Tablix to show all the fields from the table
- a filter where the user can select between the available dropdowns in `col1` (de-duplicated)
- a text filter that allows nulls where a user can filter on `col2`
- the parameters will have default values so the table will load on page load

So I have a dataset with a query like so:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE col1 IN (@col1options) AND (@col2value IS NULL OR col2 = @col2value)
```

Then for `col1options` I would make **available** and **default** options be `Get values from a query` and I would use the above dataset and `col1`.

But this won't work since the query/dataset depends on `col1options` which gets its default values from the query/dataset.

I can use a second dataset but that means making multiple calls to the SQL server and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Can you post some example data? Show the before and after results.

Comment: I updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your issue so this is a guess...

If you mean you want to be able to filter your data by choosing one or more entries from a specific column in the table, but this column has duplicates and you want your parameter list to not show duplicates then this is what do to.

1. Create a new report
2. Add dataset `dsMain` as `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN (@myParam)`
3. Add dataset `dsParamValues` as `SELECT DISTINCT myColumn FROM myTable ORDER BY myColumn`
4. Edit the @myParam parameter properties and set the available and default values to a query, then choose `dsParamValues`
5. Add you table/matrix control and set it's dataset property to `dsMain`

Comment: This would need two calls to the SQL server. Is there no way to do what I want without making multiple calls? I updated my question with more details.

Comment: No, only datasets that are required to populate parameters are executed prior to the report being displayed so you can;t access the results of your main dataset until the report is run and by that time you already need the report parameter dataset to have run.

Comment: So that is two calls, right? One call to populate the parameters and one to get the data. And this way the values in the filter drop down would be everything and it wouldn't be filtered based on the other criteria from `dsMain`.

Comment: That's correct. Maybe you having made your requirements clear. If not, update your question with a sample of data and expected process/output.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution.

1. Follow [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36632.ssrs-remove-duplicate-filter-values-from-parameter-drop-down-using-vb-code.aspx) to build the "dummy" hidden parameter, the visible paramter and the de-dupe VBA code
2. Add a tablix properties filter where **param** is **in** the **visible / non-hidden parameter from above VBA** (FYI double click to add parameter)
3. Adding via double click will append a **(0)** at the end, remove the **(0)**

It should work as expected at that point! You should be able to select one, some or all parameters and your report should update accordingly.